# Import flat file containing commas/quotes into SAP BODS

Tags: file-format, sap-data-services

Hi I have a row like following in .csv file

> 12346,abcded,ssadsadc,2013.04.04 08.42.31,8,"I would like to use an
>   existing project as a template for a new project for another Report
>   Suite but it just overwrites the existing project rather than creates
>   new one even when I use the ""Save As"" function.",Analyst,,5,"Hotel
>   Room,Literature,Open/ Create",,

the text string has `"` and `,` as part of the string. Hence I am not able to use `"` as text delimiter in SAP BODS file format.

Could somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a delimiter that is not expected to be in your data (ex. ~ or | ) or a string of multiple characters (ex. $^$ )