# Reading csv file with double quote delimiter in SAP BODS

Tags: csv, delimiter, sap-data-services

I am trying to read a csv file in SAP BODS 
the file delimiter is ,(comma) and text delimiter is "(double quotes)
the text withing the ""  AND COMMAS also have double quotes in them 
due to which the column is being split into new column

Is there any way i can only use header columns as a reference for the column definition?

Comment: give csv sample, please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load the data from a flat file using SAP BODS which contain commas and quotes as part of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677937/how-to-load-the-data-from-a-flat-file-using-sap-bods-which-contain-commas-and-qu)