# Reading CSV file in SAP Data Services using double quotes as text delimiter - but only single double quotes in column value

Tags: csv, delimiter, sap-data-services

I am reading a CSV file in SAP Data Services Designer and using `"` as text delimiter. The client sometimes sends data that only has one double quote in a column, without a closing `"` which would mark the end of string.

Because of this, it ends up reading next many rows as one single column, until it encounters the next `"`.

I need to retain the `"` as text delimiter as that is also required.

Is there a way to avoid the anomaly where the software only sees one `"`?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import flat file containing commas/quotes into SAP BODS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677937/import-flat-file-containing-commas-quotes-into-sap-bods)

Comment: Hi @Suncatcher. Unfortunately it doesn't. The data in my case is sent by the client so we can't make changes to it.

Comment: don't duplicate the same questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61456032/reading-csv-file-with-double-quote-delimiter-in-sap-bods, make research before posting